# mvn dependency:tree return nothing but build success

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am looking for any dependency conflict in `aspectjrt` however when I run `mvn dependency:tree` command it shows nothing but `Build Success`, but I can clearly see the dependency declared in the pom.xml

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=aspectjrt > maven.tree.txt
```

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

result

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MySmallApplication-1.10.war
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ MySmallApplication ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.912 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-13T11:21:43-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/436M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: What happens if you run it without `-Dincludes=aspectjrt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation regarding [-Dincludes](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes)

You should use the format: `[groupId]:[artifactId]:[type]:[version]`

Try running something like this:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.7.3 > maven.tree.txt
```